# Delphi - Chat com Emoticons

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Eu acredito que existe muitas e muitas pessoas com essa mesma dúvida, infelizmente não achei nada no google que pudesse me ajudar então gostaria da solidariedade e ajuda do pessoal aqui, Como eu poderia fazer um chat com emotions em Delphi XE8, Já vi dizerem que dá para fazer pelo "RichEdit" porem infelizmente esse componente não existe para Multi-device no Delphi xe8 ... Então eu venho aqui pedir a ajuda, Alguém sabe como posso colocar emoticons? oque posso usar? o memo funcionaria e como? qual outro componente seria melhor? Help